# How to add an automatic reminder from phonegap application

Tags: json, html, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I am developing an phone gap-androidg app and i want to add a predefined reminder through the application .Where reminder must be predefined by me.
Something like "you have 2 days more to return the library book "

Comment: what have you tried ? what kind of reminder, push notification or on-screen popup ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.I'm new to whole mobile app development.I want to use push notifications.Can you suggest me any links to follow .

Comment: You should read Cordova's documentation about push notification and start writing codes first. Ask here when you're stuck in programming

Comment: okay :) do you think Google API push notifications is a good way?

Comment: Yes, for Android of course

Comment: yeah i tried that.But I don't get an API key when go to API access.I did just the way it was told in a tutorial i read.Can i have little help there if can.I am doing this android app as part of my 3rd year project.I am a network engineering student and i don't have much idea about mobile app development.I'm very desperate because I have only 1 month to finish this .It will be great help.Thanx in advance

Comment: You should apply for API access if you work in Android / iOS development. Of course, payment involved.

Comment: oh really :( I'll have to think about it then considering the budget of the project.thanx :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

here you can add predefined or schedule notification inside you app like

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title : "Reminder",
            text: "you have 2 days more to return the library book"
});